# NPE on ManyToMany in DataNucleus

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, datanucleus

I have this entity

```
@Entity
public class ContactList extends Base {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = BaseEntity.serialVersionUID;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<User> contacts = new HashSet<User>();

    public ContactList() {
    }

    public Collection<User> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(Collection<User> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

}
```

and whatever method I call from the Spring Data repository, like `findAll()`, I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.assertCompatibleFieldType(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1005) ~[datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getBackingStoreForField(RDBMSStoreManager.java:965) ~[datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.BulkFetchExistsHelper.getSQLStatementForContainerField(BulkFetchExistsHelper.java:93) ~[datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JPQLQuery.java:894) ~[datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery.compileInternal(JPQLQuery.java:296) ~[datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1801) ~[datanucleus-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1747) ~[datanucleus-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:197) ~[datanucleus-api-jpa-4.1.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:55) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Any idea why?

I also tried adding `targetEntity = User.class` to @ManyToMany.
I'm using DataNucleus 1.4.1.

I found in the log the following lines that could be relevant:

```
DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema - DEBUG: Field [ContactList.contacts] -> Column(s) [contactlist.contacts] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.TypeConverterMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.datastore.VarCharRDBMSMapping) 
...
DataNucleus.Persistence - WARN : Member ContactList.contacts in table=contactlist has mapping=org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.TypeConverterMapping@6296ccf7 but expected mapping type=class org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.CollectionMapping
```

Comment: This is happening because from `org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.BulkFetchExistsHelper#getSQLStatementForContainerField():93` the method `storeMgr.getBackingStoreForField(clr, mmd, null);` (so `type` is `null`) is called and further down the road `type` is accessed without any additional checks.

Comment: That's true. But if the exception is thrown, I don't think NPE is the desired behavior. 
Anyway, I also found this in the log `DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema - DEBUG: Field [ContactList.contacts] -> Column(s) [contactlist.contacts] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.TypeConverterMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.datastore.VarCharRDBMSMapping)`. I edited the question to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a `Converter` was automatically applied. But I think this is an issue with DataNucleus, because that converter was declared something like this

```
public class ListOfMyEnumsToStringAttributeConverter 
    extends CollectionOfEnumsToStringAttributeConverter<MyEnum, List<MyEnum>>
    implements AttributeConverter<List<MyEnum>, String>
```

Another issue with DataNucleus is that NPE is thrown even though a warning/error message should be logged.

And last, but not least, when a converter is automatically applied and this leads to an error, the converter class should be part of the log message.

Comment: If this isn't supposed to work, then an exception with a clear message should be thrown. But you can annotate a `Collection` with `@Basic`, so ...